# Spatial Engine Connection Failed error with ArcGIS

Tags: arcgis-desktop, postgresql

I have a database on **PostgreSQL 9.5** when I try to connect to the database in **ArcGIS** desktop I get this message in log:

> CAN'T OPEN INSTANCE: sde:postgresql. Spatial Engine Connection Failed
>   (-51)

After that I have an error:

> ev.SQLstate = 42501 SDE DBMS Error: -25  ERROR:  must be owner of
>   database base ev.SQLstate = 42P01 SDE DBMS Error: -37  ERROR: 
>   relation "sde.sde_layers" does not exist LINE 1: select count(*) from
>   sde.sde_layers
>
> File pg_hba.conf changed and users have CONNECT privileges.

What is the problem?

I'm following **Esri** instruction.

Answer (score 1):

The problem was in ODBC driver. After installing proper driver version -x86, connect have created. But One problem still remains - ArcGIS desktop doesn't recognize spatial objects in tables. There is a **geometry type** field in table, but it recognizes as **String**